# View mess up when i add new tab bar item

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have view like in first picture
[image: first picture]

When i add new tab bar item to the view, it will mess up like below picture (Second picture). I don't know what is the problem, how can i solve this? Thank You!

[image: second picture]

Answer (score 0):

Now using tab bar controller you can add the new tabbar item for a new controller by following these steps:

- Drag a tab bar controller onto the storyboard.
- Drag a view controller.
- Open view controller's connections inspecter and find relationship under presenting segues.
- Drag from a little circle in front of it to the tab bar controller.Then click on viewcontrollers.

Your connections inspecter for the new viewcontroller should look like the below image. (View Controller seen in the image is the subclass of UITabBarController associated with the tab bar controller)

[image]

Comment: It is not solved. I created a new project and put tab view controller but it half blue. I don't understand why.

Comment: How it is looking when u drag a tab view controller? When i do it, it comes messed up like below pictures.

Comment: Actually i want to add tab bar controller too. But when i do that it messed up. I downloaded a example tab bar project from github but that also seems messed up. I think there is a problem with my Xcode?

Comment: Try without using the tab bar controller.

Comment: Share the github link please.I would try  if I can help

Comment: When i add a tab view controller or a new tab bar item, the problem same. It messed up. Here is the problem. (This is a new project and i just drag tab view controller nothing http://imgur.com/a/s3T5h

Comment: I close and reopened my mac and it seems like fixed. I don't know why. Thank you, i'll post further informations.

Comment: Good for you. Anyhow I updated the answer to add a new tab to a tab bar controller for anyone else to see. :)

Comment: The same problem appears again.